# How to merge several dataframes from a folder into a single dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I have a folder of csv files and each file has a dataframe that looks like this. Here are examples of two of the dataframes:

`df1` & `df2`:

```
Name     Level
Meg      1
Ben      2
Andy     3
Vern     4
Oscar    5

Name     Level
Hanna    1
Ron      2
Sal      3
```

This is the code that I have so far that reads in the dataframes within the folder:

```
def match_folder(folderpath, exportfile):
    vals = []
    directory = os.fsencode(folderpath)
    os.chdir(directory)
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            df1 = pd.read_csv(filename)
            vals.append(df1)
```

Not really sure what I do after this point.

I want the final output to be:

```
Name     Level
Meg      1
Ben      2
Andy     3
Vern     4
Oscar    5
Hanna    1
Ron      2
Sal      3
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC we can use [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) method:

```
import glob

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob('/path/to/*.csv')], ignore_index=True)
```